# JavaFX determinate if key pressed between a and Z

Tags: keycode

I have a `ListView<String>` in JavaFX and would like to determinate if the user presses a key between a(lowercase) and Z(uppercase).

My code to handle it looks like this:

```
@FXML
private void chooseElementByKey(KeyEvent event){
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB){
        textfieldElement.setText("Element 1");
        event.consume();
        textfieldElement.requestFocus();
    }else if(/*put magic here*/){
        //more magic ...
    }
}
```

So I want to determinate if a key between a and Z is pressed. There must be a better way then

`if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.a || event.getCode() == KeyCode.b` ... and so on

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you do something like `if (event.getCode() >= KeyCode.a && event.getCode() <= KeyCode.Z)`? The [`KeyCode` type is just an `enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html), but I don't know Java well, not entirely sure if you can evaluate it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the link in my comment:

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyCode.html

`KeyCode` has `isLetterKey()` which:

> Returns true if this key code corresponds to a letter key

So I believe you should also be able to do `if(event.getKeyCode().isLetterKey())`. However, it doesn't define what is considered "a letter key", so I'm not 100% sure this will work for you if you don't want to allow non-English characters for example.

Edit: According to this link:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090108

There are some bugs with `isLetterKey()`'s handling of non-English characters, ex:

> KeyCode.isLetterKey returns false for Swedish letters ö, ä and å.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question has already been answered, I'm going to make another contribution for those, who can't use the `isLetterKey()` method.

**A - Z**

For those who just don't want (or even can't) use the `isLetterKey()` function, this would be a good way to solve it:

```
if(ke.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_A && ke.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_Z) {
    //do Something
}
```

**With Special Chars**

For those who cannot access the `isLetterKey()` function due to special chars in their language, there is also the following possibility:

*1. Create a char array, containing all special chars*

```
char[] specialChars = {'ä', 'ö', 'ü'};
boolean foundSpecialChar = false;
```

*2. Compare the content of your array with the `KeyCode()`*

```
for(int i = 0; i < specialChars.length; i++) {
    if(ke.getKeyChar() == specialChars[i]) {
        foundSpecialChar = true;
    }
}
```

*3. add an additional check to the if condition of the A - Z example*

```
if((ke.getKeyCode() >= KeyEvent.VK_A && ke.getKeyCode() <= KeyEvent.VK_Z) || foundSpecialChar) {
//do Something here
}
```